# Total Commander external editor emacs "permission denied" on editing files

Tags: emacs, total-commander

I configured my Total Commander so I can open a file *.txt i.e. within emacs.

Therefore I setup my Editor
`D:\Tools\emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe "%1"`

When I now open my file everything is ok. But when I edit it and save it emacs tells me the following:

> Saving file c:/log.txt...
>
> basic-save-buffer-2: Opening output file: permission denied, c:/log.txt

How do I make it run so it can actually edit files?

Comment: I think this might be a problem with Windows permissions.  You could change the security settings of emacsclientw.exe to have it run as administrator.  While that is not a good final solution, it would tell us whether or not we had a permissions issue here.

Comment: It's highly likely that you do *not* have permission to write to the C: top-level directory as a non-administrator.  Before going the route of having Emacs run as administrator, though, consider *why* you want to write to c:*; is there some other program creating c:/log.txt?  That seems very odd.

Comment: Was just a test, but u guys are right its becuz i do not have permissions

Answer (score 0):

By Default you should not be saving anything to root `C:\`

It is just bad practice and by default a normal user does not have permission to it.

Instead, create a working DIR in your `Documents` folder and a log directory in that, then you will have something like:

```
C:\Users\Frank\Documents\Working\logs\log.txt
```

This should not create any permission errrors.